# Installing NGINX from source with pcre and openssl throws error on make

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, nginx

I'm attempting to install NGINX from source on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS [via DigitalOcean] but I'm having issues during the *make* process.

Here is my bash script:

```
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz
tar xzf nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre2-10.20.tar.gz
tar xzf pcre2-10.20.tar.gz
wget http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
tar xzf zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
wget https://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2e.tar.gz
tar xzf openssl-1.0.2e.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.8.0
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --conf-path=/usr/local/nginx/etc/nginx.conf --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre=/root/src/pcre2-10.20 --with-zlib=/root/src/zlib-1.2.8 --with-openssl=/root/src/openssl-1.0.2e
make
```

I get the following errors:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/src/pcre2-10.20'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `libpcre.la'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/src/pcre2-10.20'
make[1]: *** [/root/src/pcre2-10.20/.libs/libpcre.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/src/nginx-1.8.0'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

I checked the gcc version using `gcc -v` and it says 4.8.4.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the PCRE version I was using was the wrong one, so I changed to version 1 and everything worked. Here's the updated bash script:

```
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz
tar xzf nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre-8.38.tar.gz
tar xzf pcre-8.38.tar.gz
wget http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
tar xzf zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
wget https://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2e.tar.gz
tar xzf openssl-1.0.2e.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.8.0
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --conf-path=/usr/local/nginx/etc/nginx.conf --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre=/root/src/pcre-8.38 --with-zlib=/root/src/zlib-1.2.8 --with-openssl=/root/src/openssl-1.0.2e
make
```

Thanks to @EtanReiser for the find.

Comment: I changed `--with-pcre=/root/src/pcre2-10.20` to `--with-pcre` and it seems to be working now, but I don't know why. I guess this means that it will use system pcre instead of the one I defined, but I don't know enough to know how this works.

Comment: Did you build pcre and openssl in those locations already?

Comment: @EtanReisner No. From the documentation for NGINX I believe it says it'll take care of that.

Comment: The [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html) also seem to indicate a maximum PCRE version of 8.32. (Not PCRE2 10.20.) Though I suspect that the now current PCRE 8.38 may very well work.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ok, I must have missed that. I tried it again with 8.38 and the make worked without errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of PCRE.

You are trying to use the PCRE2 version of the library but nginx requires the PCRE version of the library.

From the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html):

> `--with-pcre=path` — sets the path to the sources of the PCRE library. The library distribution (version 4.4 — 8.32) needs to be downloaded from the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) site and extracted. The rest is done by nginx’s `./configure` and `make`. The library is required for regular expressions support in the [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directive and for the [ngx_http_rewrite_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx has compile dependencies. Other than being able to compile C you'll need:

```bash
sudo apt-get install \
    libpcre3   libpcre3-dev \
    zlib1g     zlib1g-dev \
    libssl-dev
```

Comment: please look again at your answer ;) The first line makes no sense. 
I would put all the dependencies that are not already pulled automatically in one line. 
The libraries look helpful but maybe give some explanation what you are doing and how this relates to the question. No bad feelings ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).